# How to implement UISearchController with objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchcontroller

I have an existing app, written in objective-c, with a table view.

I am now trying to go back to this app and add a search bar to the table.

The problem is that now there is the new `UISearchController` protocol, there seems to be very little information online in how to implement this within objective-c - all tutorials and examples that I can find are all for Swift.

I have added the delegates to the .h file:

```
UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating
```

And I have the following code in `viewDidLoad`, which works and adds a search bar:

```
// Search controller
searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

// Add the search bar
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
[searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
```

And that is as far as I have got!

I would appreciate any pointers, example code or tutorials on how to implement the new UISearchController in an existing objective-c app tableview.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I found this following example code, which has been the most useful example I have found so far:  https://github.com/Ja5onHoffman/UISearchController-Demo

Answer (score 25):

Initialise Following things as per steps mentioned.

**1) Protocol declaration in** `<UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating>` in the .h interface class

**2) Declare following properties**

```
//Fetch result controller 
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;

//for the results to be shown with two table delegates
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLCustomerResultrowsItemsCellController *searchResultsController;

//this custom controller is only suppose to have number of rows and cell for row function of table datasource
```

**3) For state restoration**

```
 @property BOOL searchControllerWasActive;
 @property BOOL searchControllerSearchFieldWasFirstResponder;
```

**4) Initialise the code in this step in ViewDidload**

```
_searchResultsController = [[CLChatContactsSearchResultController alloc] init];
_searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:_searchResultsController];

self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = nil; 
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
self.contactsTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;


// we want to be the delegate for our filtered table so didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called for both tables
self.searchResultsController.tableView.delegate = self;
self.searchController.delegate = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = YES; // default is YES
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self; // so we can monitor text changes + others

// Search is now just presenting a view controller. As such, normal view controller
// presentation semantics apply. Namely that presentation will walk up the view controller
// hierarchy until it finds the root view controller or one that defines a presentation context.
//
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;  // know where you want UISearchController to be displayed
```

**5) Use Button even to initiate the controller and past these functions for future usage if any see comments**

```
#pragma mark - UISearchBarDelegate

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}


#pragma mark - UISearchControllerDelegate

// Called after the search controller's search bar has agreed to begin editing or when
// 'active' is set to YES.
// If you choose not to present the controller yourself or do not implement this method,
// a default presentation is performed on your behalf.
//
// Implement this method if the default presentation is not adequate for your purposes.
//
- (void)presentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {

}

- (void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    // do something before the search controller is presented
}

- (void)didPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    // do something after the search controller is presented
}

- (void)willDismissSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    // do something before the search controller is dismissed
}

- (void)didDismissSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    // do something after the search controller is dismissed
}
```

**6) On searching in text you get this callback**

```
#pragma mark - UISearchResultsUpdating

- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {

    // update the filtered array based on the search text
    NSString *searchText = searchController.searchBar.text;

    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [_fetchedResultsController.sections objectAtIndex:0];

    if (searchText == nil) {

        // If empty the search results are the same as the original data
        self.searchResults = [sectionInfo.objects mutableCopy];

    } else {

        NSMutableArray *searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        NSArray *allObjects = sectionInfo.objects;

        for (PhoneNumber *phoneMO in allObjects) {

            if ([phoneMO.number containsString:searchText] || [[phoneMO.closrr_id filteredId] containsString:searchText] || [[phoneMO.contact.fullname lowercaseString] containsString:[searchText lowercaseString]]) {
                [searchResults addObject:phoneMO];
            }
        }

        self.searchResults = searchResults;

    }

    // hand over the filtered results to our search results table
    CLCustomerResultrowsItemsCellController *tableController = (CLCustomerResultrowsItemsCellController *)self.searchController.searchResultsController;
    tableController.filteredContacts = self.searchResults;
    [tableController.tableView reloadData];
}
```

**7) You have to declare the filteredContacts property in the Custom class that will fill the searched items .**

**8) Thats it , in did select row compare the table view if its the main controller or custom controller class table view and do the operation for the selected item.**

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Could you tell, what is `CLCustomerResultrowsItemsCellController`? It gives me error and can not be imported.

Comment: Oh CLCustomerResultrowsItemsCellController is nothing just a tableviewcontroller class with two methods and a property filteredresults nsmutablearray. The number of rows to mention the items found on reload and cellforrowatindexpath to create a cell by using a confirgurecell:... check the IOS TableViewcontroller with uisearchcontroller example its more easy to solve an understand.

Comment: If you like the answer and solved your purpose please accept the answer and tick :)

Comment: Oh, it i not my question, can I still accept the answer? I am going to implement it this way and if it works, I will definitely vote it up.

Comment: Are you using any `.xib` files at all? I would think that `UISearchController` should have its `.xib`. It would be much better if you could please add some additional files, like this custom `CLCustomerResultrowsItemsCellController` and clarify workflow a bit, explain it in more detail, especially, how `UISearchController` interacts with another custom `UITableViewController`, and then, which controller should have `.xib` to customize actual view. Should we put `UISearchBar` OR `UISearchBar and Search Display Controller` in the `.xib`?

Comment: What is `self.contactsTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar`? It gives me error. Seems like I do not have `constactsTableView` property.

Comment: What is `_fetchedResultsController` in `UISearchResultsUpdating`? It gives me error too.

Comment: I asked another question trying to get more clarification, take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906239/further-clarification-of-how-to-implement-uisearchcontroller-with-objective-c

Comment: What is self.contactsTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar? It gives me error. Seems like I do not have constactsTableView property. – - This is to assign the search bar to the main table for the searching , you can use your own as well and assign to the search controller searchbar..

Comment: I solved it already the way Apple docs recommend and will post the answer soon to the question that I asked in relation to yours. The line is how Apple suggests to do it: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/   I tried your code straight the way you wrote it and whatever I did I was not able to make it working, so I assume that your answer is still not accepted because there is not enough of detail on how you did it. Could you add the minute details and clarifications?

Comment: Ah, no sorry, misread it. In my original post I have not implemented Apple's suggestion. It IS present in your code: `self.contactsTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar` in `4) Initialise the code in this step in ViewDidload` 7th line, no?

Comment: 7th line, no? I didn't get this , did it solved your purpose ?

Comment: This was in response to your post: `What is self.contactsTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar? It gives me error. Seems like I do not have constactsTableView property. – - This is to assign the search bar to the main table for the searching , you can use your own as well and assign to the search controller searchbar.. –` You have `conactsTableView` property above in your code. No, it is not important anymore. I solved it differently, but used your template. Posted my answer to the linked question that I asked:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906239/further-clarification-of-how-to-implement-uisearchcontroller-with-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

I created(and it's public for you to download) a [Sample code on Objective-C](https://github.com/MDOBreno/BMOUISearchController/tree/7235fc904e8ff2dd0d150f0e2302cf698ae53b3a), that I translated from [a swift tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHsGgvIZWVM).