# Further clarification of "How to implement UISearchController with objective c"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have been trying to implement `UISearchController` by following stackoverflow thread:

[How to implement UISearchController with objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32169796/how-to-implement-uisearchcontroller-with-objective-c/33779864?noredirect=1#comment55543846_33779864)

and Apples's documentation, but can't make it working. When the initial controller (`EVTSearchViewController` which is defined as `UIViewController`) that complies with `UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UITableViewDelegate` 
(I needed to make it compliant with `UITableViewDelegate` too, since I am making it a delegate of the other `UITableViewController` type `EVTSearchResultsViewController *resultsController`s tableView) delegates is presented, I see my `.xib` with the `UISearchBar` and `UITableView`, I click the search bar and start typing:

[image]

When I type one letter, search bar disappears and nothing is shown:

[image]

First, I do not want the search bar to disappear. Second, `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` seems not to be called at all since `NSLog()` set up there does not produce any output when I am typing in the search bar.

I have `.xib` for the `EVTSearchViewController` and it has a `UISearchBar` that I am connecting to the respective property: `IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar` which is then made to point to the UISearchControllers' searchBar:

```
self.searchBar = self.searchController.searchBar
```

There is also `UITableView` that I put below the `UISearchBar` in the `.xib`. Another controller that I am using inside `EVTSearchViewController` is `EVTSearchResultsViewController`, it is `UITableViewController` and it does not have its `.xib`.

Below is the code for `viewDidLoad` and `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` methods:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
_resultsController = [[EVTSearchResultsViewController alloc] init];
_searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:_resultsController];

self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = nil;
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
self.searchBar = self.searchController.searchBar;


// we want to be the delegate for our filtered table so didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called for both tables
self.resultsController.tableView.delegate = self;
self.searchController.delegate = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = YES; // default is YES
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self; // so we can monitor text changes + others

// Search is now just presenting a view controller. As such, normal view controller
// presentation semantics apply. Namely that presentation will walk up the view controller
// hierarchy until it finds the root view controller or one that defines a presentation context.
//
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;  // know where you want UISearchController to be displayed
}

- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {

// update the filtered array based on the search text
NSString *searchText = searchController.searchBar.text;
NSLog(@"searchText: %@", searchText);
if (searchText == nil) {

    // If empty the search results are the same as the original data
    self.searchResults = [[[EVTItemStore sharedStore] allItems] mutableCopy];

} else {

    NSMutableArray *searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSArray *allEvents = [[EVTItemStore sharedStore] allItems];
    NSLog(@"allEvents: %@", allEvents);
    for (EVTItem *event in allEvents) {

        /*if ([event.number containsString:searchText] || [[phoneMO.closrr_id filteredId] containsString:searchText] || [[phoneMO.contact.fullname lowercaseString] containsString:[searchText lowercaseString]]) {
            [searchResults addObject:phoneMO];
        }*/
        if ([event.eventName containsString:searchText]) {
            [searchResults addObject:event];
        }
    }

    self.searchResults = searchResults;

}

// hand over the filtered results to our search results table
EVTSearchResultsViewController *resultsController = (EVTSearchResultsViewController *)self.searchController.searchResultsController;
resultsController.filteredEvents = self.searchResults;
[resultsController.tableView reloadData];
}
```

The respective `@properties` defined in `EVTSearchViewController`:

```
@interface EVTSearchViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) EVTSearchResultsViewController *resultsController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *searchResults;

// For state restoration
@property BOOL searchControllerWasActive;
@property BOOL searchControllerSearchFieldWasFirstResponder;

@end
```

Then, here is the code for `EVTSearchResultsViewController`:

```
#import "EVTSearchResultsViewController.h"

@implementation EVTSearchResultsViewController

- (instancetype)init
{
// Call the superclass's designated initializer
self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

if (self) {
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]
       forCellReuseIdentifier:@"UISearchViewCell"];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [self.filteredEvents count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UISearchViewCell"
                                forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.textLabel.text = self.filteredEvents[indexPath.row];

return cell;
}

@end
```

The methods of `EVTSearchResultsViewController` above are not called at all which makes look very strange for me, why do we need it at all, then?

I tried to set `UISearchBar` the way Apple docs recommend:

```
self.resultsTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
```

but it gives me a non-responsive search box, so when pressing nothing happens.

Could anyone, please, help with resolving the question. The other question linked above can also be clarified then. Thank you.

Comment: Your implementation seems overly complex. You generally want to add the uisearchbar to the tableview you want to search not spread across multiple classes and xib's. Try starting from scratch with a very simple example until you get the coding pattern down.

Comment: well, I believe that all of the things are required and should be done in this way (or similar way), and it can not be more simple. If you look at apple docs, it is already pretty complex: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/

Comment: The methods are called right now, so I see workflow better. I have two main problems right now: the one that images represent above when one view runs over another; the other is that `NSString *searchText = searchController.searchBar.text` in `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` is somehow not set when I type text.

Comment: Main problem that I have right now is the one shown above when one view runs over another. I solved the issue of setting the text (I just see right NSLog() outputs)

Comment: You should use this line from the documentation: self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar; As I suggested in my first comment, see the link you sent me for more details.

Comment: With the approach I am using above, things are working perfect in console (unfortunately, not showing up correctly). Apple's approach leads to completely unresponsive `UISearchBar`, do you know why it might happen? There are no errors in the console, it just does not respond.

Comment: Did you delete the search bar you dragged out in IB?

Comment: @beyowulf It is fine, I made it working, so the problem is solved. Your advice was right, I should have used apple's suggestion. The unresponsiveness was related to delegates issues / .xib files for sure.

Comment: Will post the answer soon.

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

So, I solved the issue and implemented basic search with `UISearchController`. Here is what we need to do to implement the basic search:

1. Create two `UITableViewControllers` classes with NO `.xib` files. Yes, there should be no `.xib` files and we are just creating two classes. In the code below their names are `EVTSearchViewController` and `EVTSearchResultsViewController`.
2. Make one of the controllers to comply with the delegates: `<UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating>`

Here is the code for the header file of `EVTSearchViewController`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface EVTSearchViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating>

@end
```

Here is the `EVTSearchResultsViewController`'s header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface EVTSearchResultsViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *filteredEvents;

@end
```

The `NSMutableArray *filteredEvents` will hold the results of the search. We should NOT implement any of the `UITableViewController` delegate methods in `EVTSearchViewController.m`, but should in `EVTSearchResultsViewController.m`.

Here is the top part of `EVTSearchViewController`:

```
#import "EVTSearchViewController.h"
#import "EVTSearchResultsViewController.h"

// Importing the class that stores `EVTItem` object classes
#import "EVTItemStore.h"
#import "EVTItem.h"

@interface EVTSearchViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;
// We created this class
@property (nonatomic, strong) EVTSearchResultsViewController *resultsController;
// array to hold the results of the search
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *searchResults;

@end
```

Here is the code for `EVTSearchViewController`'s `viewDidLoad:` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.resultsController = [[EVTSearchResultsViewController alloc] init];
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.resultsController];

self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = nil;
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
// This line of code is very important. Here we are using apple docs'
// suggestion. UITableViewController has tableView property, so
// we are just setting tableView`s header to apples' UISearchController`s' `searchBar property
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

self.searchController.delegate = self;

// default is YES
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = YES;

// so we can monitor text changes + other changes
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

// know where you want UISearchController to be displayed
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
}
```

Then we add to `EVTSearchViewController` the following method:

```
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {

// update filtered array based on the search text
NSString *searchText = searchController.searchBar.text;
if (searchText == nil) {

    // If empty the search results should be the same as the original data
    self.searchResults = [[[EVTItemStore sharedStore] allItems] mutableCopy];

} else {

    NSMutableArray *searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// [[EVTItemStore sharedStore] allItems] message retrieves
// all of the objects that I have in datastore EVTItemStore
    NSArray *allEvents = [[EVTItemStore sharedStore] allItems];

// EVTItem class has a property eventName which we are using
// for searching, then adding it to our searchResults array
    for (EVTItem *event in allEvents) {
        if ([event.eventName containsString:searchText]) {
            [searchResults addObject:event];
        }
    }

    self.searchResults = searchResults;
}

// hand over the filtered results to our search results table
EVTSearchResultsViewController *resultsController = (EVTSearchResultsViewController *)self.searchController.searchResultsController;
resultsController.filteredEvents = self.searchResults;
[resultsController.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Another controller's `EVTSearchResultsViewController` @implementation part looks like this:

```
@implementation EVTSearchResultsViewController

- (instancetype)init
{
// Call the superclass's designated initializer
self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

if (self) {
}
return self;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [self.filteredEvents count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UISearchViewCell"
                                forIndexPath:indexPath];
EVTItem *event = self.filteredEvents[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = event.eventName;
return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]
                         forCellReuseIdentifier:@"UISearchViewCell"];
}

@end
```

That's it. If we need to further customize our cells, we should be able to do it by making `UISearchViewCell.xib` for `EVTSearchResultsViewController`, and using the following `viewDidLoad` instead:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Load the NIB file
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"UISearchViewCell" bundle:nil];

// Register this NIB which contains the cell
[self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"UISearchViewCell"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your everything. :)